# How can I get a list of cells that exceed a certain length?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a massive Google Sheet and I'm trying to get a list of cells that would exceed a certain number of characters.

I've tried various methods, but I can't seem to get what I'm looking for. Since this would be across multiple sheets, I would much rather use a portable formula than setting up a filter with conditional formatting. Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try in row 1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A:A)>50, A:A, ))
```

Comment: Hm... not quite. This just copies the data to each row that exceeds the count. I'd still have to filter after that, but it's close enough.

Comment: try: `=FILTER(A:A, LEN(A:A)>50)`